# How to make xunit mock call actual method implementation, during unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit

I'm unittesting a big method, which I'm not able to make any changes to. For that job im using xUnit, and we have mocked some static classes which are used in this method unittest im doing.

What im doing here is actually a big integration test in a unit test, i know that is not optimal, but that is the situation as it stands right now.

The static class is mocked like this.

```
private readonly Mock<IStaticClass> _mockStaticClass= new Mock<IStaticClass>() { CallBase = true};
```

During my unit test of this method lets call it .doSomethingToData(), i use methods in the static class which i mock like this.

`_mockIStaticClass.Setup(x => x.manipulateDataOneWay(It.IsAny<Class>(), It.IsAny<Class2>())).Returns(SomeObject);`

Now here comes the problem.

I also need the mocked static class to use the actual implementation of another method to manipulate data which i have put into the test with my other mockings. So i do this in my unit test.

`_mockingIStaticClass.Setup(x => x.useActualImplementationMethod(It.IsAny<int>, It.IsAny<int>)).CallBase();`

But it does not work, ive put a breakpoint into the implementation of .useActualImplementationMedhod(int, int), but the code crashes when trying to make the methodcall with a NotImplementedException, during unit test debug.

What am i doing wrong? Shouldn't the actual implementation be invoked by this ?

Thankyou all for your time, and happy easter.

Comment: You are going to need to show the subject under test and the test case as it currently stands so we have a better understanding of the actual problem.

Comment: If you mock something, everything under that mock needs to be Setup. It won't ever call the actual implementation at that point as that would defeat the point of a mock.

Comment: Thankyou Guys for your time. Nkosi, ill have to get back to you on that. Just have to figure out what code i can reveal :)

Comment: I cant reveal more structure or code. Thankyou for your time.